# MVC4 - TextboxFor add "title" attribute at the model level with the help of IMetaDataAware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

View code example:-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.tr_advert.AdvTitle, new { title = "Please provide the precise title for your product advertisement." })
```

I wish to remove the title text away from here and move it to the Model level. This way i would be able to reuse it in different views.

How can i achieve that? Please suggest the soln.

Comment: Do you want something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.tr_advert.AdvTitle, new { title = Model.tr_advert.Title})`?

Comment: yes, Can we define the title text at the model property level?

Comment: Will "Title" be the new property in the model ?

Comment: But i don't want to create a new property for the title text. Instead, i would like to use the AdvTitle.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.tr_advert.AdvTitle, new { title = Model.tr_advert.AdvTitle })
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Creating tooltips using data annotations in ASP.NET MVC

http://silverhair2010.wordpress.com/2012/10/10/creating-tooltips-using-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/

[image: Check here]

Comment: It is opening on my end.

Comment: not able means link is not working or another error is coming

Comment: The browser is just processing the url. I think it could be due to some restrictions in my corporate network..

Comment: for you i am adding image check if is is useful to you

Comment: i want to create custom attribute using the MetaDataProvider approach in Mvc 4 project but the article is based on MVC 2. Please suggest.